# Compilation of the simple pybind example fails on macos

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, macos-catalina, pybind11

I'm trying to implement the [simple add function example](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html) in the `pybind11` docs. I'm using the default mac `python3` (3.7.7), and have installed `pybind11` by `pip3 install pybind11`.

There is an `example.cpp` file:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>


int add(int i, int j)
{
        return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m)
{
        m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; //optional module docstring
        m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

I'm trying to compile this using [the default command they give for macos](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually):

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

This results in a series of errors, however:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '--extension-suffix`'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-m'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '`python3'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'pybind11'
```

What am I missing? Did I miss a step setting up `pybind11`?

Comment: `example`python3-config ...` Aren't you missing a space there?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to add a space as well but now I have another error: `clang: error: no such file or directory: '`python3-config'`

Comment: Do you remember to keep the back-tick (the backward single quote)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I just copied and pasted from their docs. The back ticks look correct. The original on their website doesn't have the space after example btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to add `pybind11` to my path separately:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/include/python3.7m/pybind11/
```